# Square Root Calculator

Tags: c#, mathematics, floating-point, iteration, numerical-methods

I have now written a simple square root calculator using the division method:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double num, sqrt = 0;
    int currentDecimal = 0, decimalAccuracyLevel, intAccuracyLevel = 5;

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
    } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num));

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the number of decimal points you wish to be accurate to: ");
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decimalAccuracyLevel) && decimalAccuracyLevel >= 0);

    while (0 < intAccuracyLevel)
    {
        double currentIncrement = Math.Pow(10, intAccuracyLevel);

        while (Math.Pow(sqrt + currentIncrement, 2) <= num)
        {
            sqrt += currentIncrement;
        }

        intAccuracyLevel--;
    }

    while (currentDecimal <= decimalAccuracyLevel)
    {
        double currentIncrement = (double)1 / Math.Pow(10, currentDecimal);

        while (Math.Pow(sqrt + currentIncrement, 2) <= num)
        {
            sqrt += currentIncrement;
        }

        currentDecimal++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sqrt);
}
```

Is there anything I should do to improve performance or accuracy?

Comment: What is your motivation for [tag:reinventing-the-wheel], and do you have a reason for picking this algorithm over, say, logarithms or Newton's Method?

Comment: I haven't written a square root solver before and I thought I might as well try it. I chose this method because I had done it this way by hand in high school, so I already knew it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your variables a near as possible to their usage.

---

Initializing multiple variables on a single line removes readability and can lead in some languages to unexpected results.

---

If you divide two numbers and one of the numbers is a `double` the result is not a integer division result, hence you don't need the cast to `double`.

---

Because you are reinventing the wheel, it would be appropriate to do the `Pow()` by your code, because otherwise you could simply use `Math.Pow(num, 0.5)`.

---

You should name your variables better. The `int currentDecimal` variable is storing the current calculated decimal points, but it reads that it holds the current Decimal number. You should rename it to `currentDecimalPoint` or something more meaningful.

---

This is a small application, but you should nevertheless extract the reading of the user input and the calculation of the result to separate methods.

Comment: Initializing multiple variables on a single line doesn't "remove" readability, but it sure hurts it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Iteratively dividing the `currentIncrement` should be faster than `Math.Pow` in the general case.

---

Handle out-of-domain values of the sqrt function.

---

Use an epsilon value to avoid infinite loops.

---

```
class Program
{
    /* Anything below epsilon is zero for us. A difference of epsilon is also considered to be zero. */
    private const double Epsilon = 1e-15;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double number;
        int significantDigits;

        /* Read parameters from console. */
        GetParameters(out number, out significantDigits);

        /* Handle imaginary numbers too. */
        bool isResultImaginary = number < 0;

        var result = Sqrt(Math.Abs(number), significantDigits);

        Console.WriteLine(isResultImaginary ? "{0}i" : "{0}", result);
    }

    private static double Sqrt(double num, int decimalAccuracyLevel)
    {
        double sqrt = 0;
        double increment = 1e5;

        /* Calculate the integral part of the result. */
        while (increment > 1)
        {
            while ((sqrt + increment) * (sqrt + increment) <= num)
            {
                sqrt += increment;
            }

            increment /= 10;
        }

        increment = 1e0;

        /* Calculate the fractional part of the result. */
        while (0 <= decimalAccuracyLevel
               && increment > Epsilon)
        {
            while ((sqrt + increment) * (sqrt + increment) <= num)
            {
                sqrt += increment;
            }

            decimalAccuracyLevel--;
            increment /= 10;
        }

        return sqrt;
    }

    private static void GetParameters(out double num, out int decimalAccuracyLevel)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
        } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num));

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number of decimal points you wish to be accurate to: ");
        } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decimalAccuracyLevel) && decimalAccuracyLevel >= 0);
    }
}
```